# Appending elements to datatables column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I currently utilize the createdRow callback to append buttons (with link) into one of the columns in a datatables.
But this doesn't work when the window is resized (smaller) and that column is hidden (only shown when expanded), since createdRow will no longer be called.
Is there any way to cater for this situation?

Updated:
Column 7 initially contains Id of the respective item (data[7]).
In the createdRow callback, I replace the Id with 3 clickable icons (view/Update/Delete).

```
createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) {
$(row).children().eq(7).html("")
    .append($("<i>").addClass("fa fa-eye mr5").attr("title", "Details").css("cursor", "pointer")
        .click(function () {
            window.location.href = self.urlViewCam + "/?id=" + encodeURIComponent(data[7]);
        }))
    .append($("<i>").addClass("fa fa-pencil mr5").attr("title", "Update").css("cursor", "pointer")
        .click(function () {
            window.location.href = self.urlUpdateCam + "/?id=" + encodeURIComponent(data[7]);
        }))
    .append($("<i>").addClass("fa fa-trash-o").attr("title", "Delete").css("cursor", "pointer")
        .click(function () {
            if (self.confirmationModal) {
                $('#divConfirmMsg').text("Do you want to delete \"" + data[0] + "\"?");
                $('#btnConfirmDelete').click(function () { deleteCamera(data[7]) });
                self.confirmationModal.modal("show");
            } else if (confirmDelete(data[0])) {
                deleteCamera(data[7]);
            }
        }));
}
```

Current workaround: When details are expanded, search for the next 'tr' (the expanded row), and modify its content.

```
$(self.detailedTableElem).on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var camName = $(this).children().eq(0).text();
    if (self.table.row($(this)).child.isShown()) {
        $(this).next('tr').find('li > span.dtr-title').each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == functionColName + ":") {
                appendIcons(camName, $(this).next('span.dtr-data'));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: could you please show us your code?

Comment: @GibboK I've updated the question with codes :)

Comment: do you use a fluid layout?

Comment: hmm.. I'm sorry I don't really know what is fluid layout. Is it the same as responsive? Responsive is set to true.

Comment: `createdRow` callback may not be suitable, try to use [render](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option in order to  provide template for column

Comment: @KostiaMololkin I managed to add in the icons through "render" by returning the .html() of the created element. But I'm struggling to implement the .click function.

Comment: @KostiaMololkin I have added a workaround on top. Do you think its an acceptable method?

Comment: @xytec as i know the modifying content manually for detail row it only option,that's why your method is ok i think))

Comment: @xytec check [example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) of details for row